# is that possible to load data of various format in date column | Oracle

Tags: oracle, date, format

Table :

```
SQL> DESC EMO_SRC;
 Name                                                  Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------------------
 EMPLOYEE_NAME                                                  VARCHAR2(30)
 EMPLOYEE_NUMBER                                                NUMBER
 STATE                                                          VARCHAR2(10)
 ZIP                                                            NUMBER
 DOB                                                            DATE
 AGE                                                            NUMBER
 SEX                                                            VARCHAR2(7)
 MARITALDESC                                                    VARCHAR2(15)
 CITIZENDESC                                                    VARCHAR2(15)
 HISPANIC_LATINO_RACEDESC                                       VARCHAR2(15)
 DATE_OF_HIRE                                                   DATE
 DATE_OF_TERMINATION                                            DATE
 REASON_FOR_TERM                                                VARCHAR2(50)
 EMPLOYMENT_STATUS                                              VARCHAR2(15)
 DEPARTMENT                                                     VARCHAR2(30)
 POSITION                                                       VARCHAR2(20)
 PAY_RATE                                                       NUMBER(6,2)
 MANAGER_NAME                                                   VARCHAR2(20)
 EMPLOYEE_SOURCE                                                VARCHAR2(30)
 PERFORMANCE_SCORE                                              VARCHAR2(40)
```

Table EMO_SRC has 3 "date" columns DOB,Date_of_hire and date_of _Termination

If

```
==========================================================
 DOB             | Date_of_hire      | date_of_termination
============================================================
 11/24/1987         10/27/2008            10/28/2016
 4-26-1984          1-06-2014
 02-26-1984         09/29/2014            4-15-2017
```

like above , the data has random date format for these 3 columns . Oracle not allowing to load '01-06-2014 ' format . 
please let me know is there any way to load date value of different format or I need to convert data to '00/00/0000' format .  Huge number of data mismatch is load . Then how, can I change and load the data in table .

```
SQL> show parameters nls_date_format;

NAME                                 TYPE       VALUE
------------------------------------ ---------- ------------------------------
nls_date_format                      string     DD-MON-RR
```

Please let me know the solution .

[image]

Comment: Which application do you use? The formatting is done by your client rather than driven by `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which tool you use.

Anyway, you have a problem. "Date" formats are different within columns and within rows which makes it even worse.

I'd suggest you to create a function which will accept input values - "dates" (actually, *strings*) you find in source data and try to convert it to a valid DATE using `TO_DATE` function with different format masks: `mm/dd/yyyy`, `dd-mm-yyyy`, etc., whichever you find in source. Use inner BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END blocks so that the first failure wouldn't terminate function's execution. If you manage to find correct date value, fine - load it. If not, log the error and try to fix it by another `TO_DATE`'s format mask. Optionally, you might use `REGEXP_LIKE` to verify input format.

Problem you can't solve is a string that looks like `10-08-20`. Which is which? Is `10` day, month or year? The same goes for other values.

Also, calling a function for all those values - if source is large - will certainly take a lot of time.